# adding list indexes in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

Say I have this list:

```
[['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '.12'], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '.13']]
```

And I want to add together the final element of each array (.12 and .13), how do I convert these strings to a real number, and add them together? Also assuming that each array in the list could be of different length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> data = [['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '.12'], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '.13']]
>>> sum(float(x[-1]) for x in data)
0.25
```

Comment: Works perfectly! One last question, is there a way to round the resulting number to 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0.
for l in listOfLists:
    sum += float(l[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
sum(map(float,(lst1[-1],lst2[-1])))
```

Sample output:

```
>>> lst1 = ["1", ".1"]
>>> lst2 = ["1", ".2"]
>>> sum(map(float,(lst1[-1],lst2[-1])))
0.30000000000000004
```

Answer (score 0):

This works -

```
>>> li = [['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '.12'], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '.13']]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:float(x[-1])+float(y[-1]), li)
0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
as_string = [['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '.12'], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '.13']]
as_numbers = [map(float, arr) for arr in as_string]
result = sum(arr[-1] for arr in as_numbers)
```

or just:

```
result = sum(float(arr[-1]) for arr in as_string)
```